# how to extract word like d1234-5678-c9876 from a string using python (regex expression)?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-group

I have to find the word like a4546-1234 or a12344-v23454-32444 out of a string. I tried various way to find out.

Comment: Post your's attemps, multiple examples of input/outputs.

Comment: I was trying for really long and I think I found the solution too.

Comment: import re


text='testing alphanumberic in python ca365-1234'
text = re.findall('([A-Za-z]+[\d]+[\w-]*|[\d-]+[A-Za-z]+[\w-]*)', text) 


print(text)

Comment: What does the string look like? Also, what have you tried and what difficulty you ran into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import re

text='use this as an example ca365-1234'

text = re.findall('([A-Za-z]+[\d]+[\w-]*|[\d-]+[A-Za-z]+[\w-]*)', text)

print(text)

I found the solution for above problem. It is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward regex for your example is probably

```
re.search("[a-z]?\d+(-[a-z]?\d+)*", mystring)
```

That will find all substrings that might start with a letter followed by multiple digits, followed by zero or more instances of '-', a possible letter, and multiple digits. But I don't know if that's actually the pattern you're looking for based on your question. What is it that all of your target strings have in common?

Answer (score 0):

This can be used

```
str= "llllkkknnnnnnnnna4546-1234bbbbbba12344-v23454-32444nnnn"
text=re.findall('((a[0-9])\w+\-[0-9].\w.)|((a[0-9])\w+\-v[0-9]\w+\-[0-9]\w...)',str)
```